# Get one div for every returned element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im stuck.

I have a button which returns information about a event, name, date and so on.

In the script it looks like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < result.length ; i++)
            {
                var item = result[i];                   
                $("#eventList").append("<h3>" + result.eventDate + "</h3>" + "<br>" + result.eventId + "<br>" + result.description + "<br>");
        }
```

This generates a list of events that goes to a div, alla of the events in one div. But i would like every event to be placed in one separate div/box.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just wrap a `<div>... </div>` around the string you append.

Answer (score 1):

You can create them inside a div and then append all of them at the end to the dom.

```
var divs = [];
var $div;

results.forEach(function(item){
    $div = $('<div></div>');
    $div.append("<h3>" + item.eventDate + "</h3>");
    $div.append("<br>"+ item.eventId);
    $div.append("<br>"+ item.description);
    divs.push($div);
});

$("#eventList").append(divs);
```

Comment: This also reduces the amount of redrawing your browser needs to do as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your item variable inside the `for` loop. When `ii` gets too big, `result[ii]` will be undefined or false, and the loop will stop. I prefer to use `ii` to `i`, because it's easier to find if I want to search for a repeat loop.

Each jQuery operation returns the jQuery object that it was applied to, so you can chain your operations. You can create an empty element, and then set its text in the next operation, to make the code more compact.

```
for(var ii=0, item; item=result[ii]; ii++) {
  $("#eventList")
  .append($("<div>")
          .append($("<h3>").text(item.eventDate))
          .append($("<p>").text(item.eventId))
          .append($("<p>").text(item.description))
  )
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a4j4rq55/)